# Convert comma-separated string to nested array, RegExp?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Got this type of string:

```
var myString = '23, 13, (#752, #141), $, ASD, (#113, #146)';
```

I need to split it to an array with comma as separator but also converts `(..)` to an array.

This is the result I want: `[23, 13, ['#752', '#141'], '$', 'ASD', ['#113', '#146']];`

I got huge data-sets so its very important to make it as fast as possible. What's the fastest way? Do some trick RegExp function or do it manually with finding indexes etc.?

Here's a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/cilakewecu/edit?js,console

Comment: If possible, format the string as a real array at source, and use JSON.parse to create an array.

Comment: I can't modify the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the parens to brackets, quote the strings, then use `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse('[' + 
  str.
    replace(/\(/g, '[').
    replace(/\)/g, ']').
    replace(/#\d+|\w+/g, function(m) { return isNaN(m) ? '"' + m + '"' : m; })
  + ']')

> [23,13,["#752","#141"],"ASD",["#113","#146"]]
```

Comment: interesting, but in expected result `23` and `13` should be number instead string

Comment: @torazaburo Tried it on my data-set and apparently sometimes the $ symbol occurs in my string.  I get Unexpected token $. Is it possible somehow to replace this to '$' or null? I updated the question.

Comment: Change `\w` to `[\w$]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegEx

```
/\(([^()]+)\)|([^,()\s]+)/g
```

[**RegEx Explanation:**](https://regex101.com/r/nZ3rR1/1)

The RegEx contain two parts. **First**, to capture anything that is inside the parenthesis. **Second**, capture simple values (string, numbers)

1. `\(([^()]+)\)`: Match anything that is inside the parenthesis.

   - `\(`: Match `(` literal.
   - `([^()]+)`: Match anything except `(` and `)` one or more number of times and add the matches in the first captured group.
   - `\)`: Match `)` literal.
2. `|`: OR condition in RegEx
3. `([^,()\s]+)`: Match any character except `,` (comma), parenthesis `(` and `)` and space one or more number of times and add the match in the second captured group

[image: RegEx Flow Diagram]

**Demo:**

```js
var myString = '23, 13, (#752, #141), ASD, (#113, #146)',
    arr = [],
    regex = /\(([^()]+)\)|([^,()\s]+)/g;

// While the string satisfies regex
while(match = regex.exec(myString)) {

    // Check if the match is parenthesised string
    // then
    //     split the string inside those parenthesis by comma and push it in array
    // otherwise
    //     simply add the string in the array
    arr.push(match[1] ? match[1].split(/\s*,\s*/) : match[2]);
}

console.log(arr);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>'; // For demo purpose only
```

Comment: `(#752", " #141)` should be array

Comment: @Grundy wrong regex in between to satisfy `$` condition by OP, updated. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Just use the `split` method.

```js
var str = '23, 13, (#752, #141), ASD, (#113, #146)',
    newstr = str.replace(/\(/gi,'[').replace(/\)/gi,']'),
    splitstr = newstr.split(',');
```

Comment: He said that splitting at the commas does not work for him because of the nested arrays.